# MIPS sw and lw question

Tags: computer-science, mips

I have seen in examples of sw and lw being used in MIPS the instruction looks like this.

```
lw $6, 0($4)
```

My first question is, what does the 0() do? What if it was lw $6, 4($4)?

I am trying to test in the MARS mips program but whenever I execute the program the lw and sw seem to not update the registers with any values. for example if I have this code

```
ori $t1, $t1, 8
lw $t2, 0($t1)
```

I would expect $t2 to be updated to some value but this is not the case. My second question is if someone could anyone explain why $t2 still holds 0x00000000 and not a value after the lw instruction is executed.

Comment: Regarding your second question, can you give some code ?

Answer (score 2):

The instruction lw {regDest}, {imm}({reg}) will load in {regDest} the contents of the word stored at effective address pointed by {reg}+imm, where inm is a 16 bit immediate.
The effective address should be multiple of 4.

For example, the code

```
  ori $t1,$0, 0x2000
  lw $t2, 4($t1)

.data 0x2000
.word 0x1234
.word 0x4321
```

will load in $t2 the contents of address 0x2004 (that is, the address pointed by $t1 which was 0x2000 plus the immediate 4, giving effective address 0x2004).

You might still get $t2=0 if the contents of that address is zero.

Answer (score 0):

0() means you will get it from the first block on the register. You can make it 1 ,2 or even 4.

If you put n(), It will get the value from the nth block you specify

Comment: what do you mean when you say block? Can you give me a simple example so I can understand what a block is referring to? Thanks @2rk